# What is the benefit of investing in company related cryptos?

Tags: cryptocurrency

I read the Cryptocurrency Investing for Dummies book’s chapter about ICOs (Initial Coin Offerings), which are similar to IPOs but instead of stock, the company issues its own themed crypto to investors. Also, they’re not regulated.

I don’t get why someone would want to participate in an ICO. I know in the case of stock IPOs, the company gets cash from investors and in turn, they give up a portion of their company ownership (hence theoretically their profits) to investors.

But it seems to me that the ICOs were a sneaky invention from companies to get cash without giving up anything, since they just created the crypto out of thin air. Also, why should the crypto’s value increase with company success? If it doesn’t represent any ownership stake in the company.

To me it looks like they are tricking fools into thinking a greater fool would later pay more for their crypto based on the company’s success (even though there’s nothing company-related (or anything at all) that backs it value)?

I read that the company could incentivize investors by making the tokens redeemable for the company’s products. In that case:

- Let’s say I own a hypothetical car company named HappyWheels which sells cars for \$ 10k. I create a crypto called WheelCoin and sell each unit of it for \$50 and accept 200 WheelCoin’s as payment for a car. In that case, “investors” are just paying for cars in advance? How would WheelCoin appreciate
  if 1/200th of \$ 10k is always \$50?

I would appreciate any clarification about this topic.

Comment: You have answered everything yourself. Some things are as stupid as you think when you read them for the first time. Of course you may wonder that you are missing something,
(how can all this even be legal?) but the simplest answer is that you do not. If you cannot understand it it is probably a scam, like most things these times.